# Add a versioning to REST api using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I know, there are a lot of discussions about how to version a REST web API. But if I do decide to add a version on the url, how do I go about it?

Suppose I have 
http://localhost/api/Person
and want to add
http://localhost/api/v2/Person

Do I create a new controller in a different namespace?
How do I add the mapping entries to route to the new controller.

Givens:
It doesn't have to work without specifying a version. In other words, I don't mind breaking what I already have if that simplifies it.

Comment: Have you read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCoreRESTfulWebAPIVersioningMadeEasy.aspx? It lays out some options. But even this question is prone to discussion.

Comment: If you don't mind breaking stuff, why do you need any versioning? BTW, you can add multiple Route's to the same action.

Comment: Yes, started with Scot's blog. That got me thinking that I might need versioning. Maybe I don't.